# JavaScript string.replace: inserting text as HTML

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace

I'm trying prepend all semicolons in a string with the HTML character `&#8239;`, which is a non-breaking thin space.

To do this, I have written this line:

```
str = str.replace( /;/g, "&#8239;;" );
```

Unfortunately, the thin space character is written in directly, instead of its HTML representation.

Is there a flag, a setting or even another function that will allow me to insert this character as HTML?

Thank you.

**Edit:** Probably should have mentioned this before: I'm working on a basic pseudocode-to-HTML converter, in which certain characters in the original string are replaced by their standard HTML equivalents.

The resulting string is then output to a div element, where I can inspect it to make sure it looks good. I then retrieve the source of this new text to place into some other web page.

But when I look at the source for the thin space, it's just the character itself, not the entity name.

(I'd paste the full source for the conversion, but it's over 300 lines.)

**Edit 2:** I was under the impression that Ctrl+U in Firefox would show the newly added characters. My mistake; they only appear when when viewing the source with Firebug (or its Webkit equivalent), or selecting the text, right-clicking and viewing the source for the selection (option only available in FF, it seems).

To test the latter approach, I created two div elements and used this JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById( "div1" ).innerHTML = ( "'&amp;'" );
document.getElementById( "div2" ).innerHTML = ( "'&#8239;'" );
```

The ampersand is displayed as `&amp;`, but the thin space's entity name is not used. This might just be weird behavior from this specific FF feature.

Comment: What really matters is what you do with the string *after* you've done that replacement. You should post that part of your code.

Comment: Why must the character be in entity form? Also, have you tried a replacement with `"&amp;#8239;;"`? I think that may solve your problem, since `&amp;` will be turned into an `&`.

Comment: I don't get it... you want a thin space characters, your you want  the characters that make up the HTML entity for the thin space?

Comment: Entities are replaced by their corresponding character during HTML parsing, i.e. when you assign that string to `.innerHTML` of a DOM element.

Comment: @MathSquared11235: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried it though, and it comes out as "&#8239;;" in the browser. What's strange is that the ampersand's entity name is preserved in the code, but the entity number I'm trying to use isn't.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Basically, when I look at the source code that JS inserted into the page, I want to see the entity number, because adding in the actual character might lead to display issues, depending on the encoding.

Comment: If you use `innerHTML` to insert the entity into the `div`, it should stay an entity in the code.

Answer (score 1):

"&#8239;" is an html entity and therefore not understood by javascript. I recommend using the String.fromCharCode() method. An example would be as follows...

`var str = 'test;here';`

`str = str.replace( /;/g, String.fromCharCode(8239) );`

`alert(str);`

You can learn more about the fromCharCode method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

Comment: That's interesting. Since the parameter specifies a Unicode value, is the function encoding-independent? The main reason I want JS to insert the entity number is to ensure I don't have to worry about question marks if the encoding isn't right, but Mozilla's documentation doesn't address this.

Comment: The function will return a string using the default encoding, which gets a little tricky with javascript as there is no true right answer. The link below is the best I have found trying to explain javascript's internal encoding. I am no expert on this subject so hopefully this helps at least point you in the right direction. http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding

Answer (score 1):

If you literally want the characters `&#8239;`, the ampersand has to be encoded as such.

```
str = str.replace( /;/g, "&amp;#8239;;" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the second semicolon in your replacement?  Shouldn't it just be:

```
str = str.replace( /;/g, "&#8239;" );
```

On my client 'str' contains the HTML entities but once you attach it to the DOM then the entities are changed into native characters.  I guess it depends on what you're using it for.  If you use 'str' as the innerText of an element then you'll see the entities and not the space.  e.g.

```
(function(s) { var x=document.createElement('div'); x.innerText=s; document.body.appendChild(x); })(str);
```

Comment: I believe the second semicolon is because he still wants a semicolon in the end string. The first semicolon ends the HTML representation string; the second is a semicolon.

Comment: nevermind I re-read your post about why you have the double ;;